# speed up docker healthcheck containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile, health-check

I'd like to speed up the container startup time but my healthcheck is not allowing me.
Let's say I'm having this healthcheck

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=300s --timeout=5s --start-period=5s --retries=3 CMD \
    curl http://localhost:<port> > /dev/null || exit 1
```

What I want is to not wait 300+ seconds to start the container but check if it is healthy after e.g. 10s [maybe the app inside it is up and running after 10 seconds] and if everything is ok to start the container.

I need the interval to be 300+ seconds as I don't want to check the internal health of it more often than 1/300

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I've updated my answer below. The setting of a start period has been implemented and will be likely released with docker engine version 25.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit 2023-07-17**

There is now support implemented for setting a `start-interval` to check in a shorter interval during the `start-period`

The feature is expected to be released in version 25 of the docker engine.

Example:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --start-period=3m --start-interval=10s \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1
```

In this example, there is a `start-interval` of **10s**, which means the first healthcheck is done **10s** after the container has been started. After that, the healthcheck is repeated every **10s**, until either the health state switches to `healthy`, or the `start-period` is over (**3m**). After that, it proceeds the healthchecks at the regular `interval` (**5m**).

Docker Docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck

Related pull request: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/40894

---

**Original Answer as of 2021**

There is currently no built in way to decrease the time, until the first healthcheck is performed. Docker always waits a full interval between the container start and the first healthcheck. The `start-period` option just defines a grace time, that allow healthchecks to fail without marking the container as unhealthy. This will only be meaningful, if the `interval` is lower than the `start-period`.

There is a feature request to add an option, that decreases the interval while the container is starting, to get the container faster into a healthy state:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33410